# How to get non-csv lines in csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a csv like:

> ```
> "Equipment","LNKEQP","METAST","METSER","MODSTA","METEOD"
> "HLL_POS_00098",1,1,0,0,0
> "TOY_GAT_00003",0,0,0,3,0
> "NAT_POS_00010",0,3,0,3,0
> "NAT_GAT_00002",0,0,0,0,0
> "NAT_GAT_00001",0,0,0,4,0
> A machine A is unavailable
> ```

And i use the code to read that csv file as:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
s=[]
for row in reader:
```

But the row doesn't contain "A machine A is unavailable", how to get this line and output as this example:

```
'METEOD': '0', 'MODSTA': '0', 'METSER': '0', 'LNKEQP': '0', 'METAST': '0', 'Equipmnt': 'NAT_VCF_00001'
'METEOD': '0', 'MODSTA': '0', 'METSER': '0', 'LNKEQP': '1', 'METAST': '1', 'Equipment': 'NAT_TVM_00002'
A machine A is unavailable
```

Thank for your help

Comment: A file with non-csv lines is not a csv file.

Comment: i know, but there are some lines in that file, i must handle them and output like the output above. Any help for such a file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the offending lines before parsing them:

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

i = """"Equipment","LNKEQP","METAST","METSER","MODSTA","METEOD"
"HLL_POS_00098",1,1,0,0,0
"TOY_GAT_00003",0,0,0,3,0
"NAT_POS_00010",0,3,0,3,0
"NAT_GAT_00002",0,0,0,0,0
"NAT_GAT_00001",0,0,0,4,0
A machine A is unavailable
"""

# Take only those lines that contain a comma.
j = "".join([line for line in StringIO(i).readlines() if ',' in line])

# Parse the taken lines as CSV.
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(j))
for line in reader:
    print line
```

Output:

```
['Equipment', 'LNKEQP', 'METAST', 'METSER', 'MODSTA', 'METEOD']
['HLL_POS_00098', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0']
['TOY_GAT_00003', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0']
['NAT_POS_00010', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0']
['NAT_GAT_00002', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['NAT_GAT_00001', '0', '0', '0', '4', '0']
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, now i know that it's better to separate them into 2 group: csv and non-csv.